# what is the standard deviation of the geometric mean sample distribution?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, mean, central-limit-theorem, geometric-mean

I wrote a python script to take a population distribution of a random variable in the interval (0,1) to be uniform and make 2 sample distribution:

- The fist is the distribution of the arithmetic mean of the samples
- The second is the distribution of the geometric mean of the samples

this what those two distribution looks like:

[image: Distributions plot]

I tested making the population distribution being other distributions too and the sample geometric mean still looking as normal (i make the Q-Q test to visualize if it's normal too). So i think it's safe to say that somehow the central limit theorem holds for the sample geometric mean distribution too, but how can we find the standard deviation of this sample distribution given the standard deviation of the population. It's well known in the arithmetic mean, we just need to divide it for $\sqrt{n}$ such that n is the sample size, but how can we do this with the geometric one?

Comment: Is your question "what is the standard deviation of the harmonic mean of $n$ independent variables from a uniform distribution over 0,1"?

Comment: The geometric mean is the exponential of the arithmetic mean of the logarithms: proceed from there.